# Client Credentials Flow - getting access token

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, spotify

How can I receive an access_token through [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) to Spotify by using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)?

Here is my code so far:

```
// Spotify API
func callAlamo(url: String) {
    let parameters = ["client_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                      "client_secret" : "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy",
                      "grant_type" : "client_credentials"]

    let headers = ["Authorization" : "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"] // <- xxx is the client_id

    Alamofire.request("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        print(response.result)
        print(response.result.value)
    })
}
```

Here is a section of my print log:

> SUCCESS
>
> Optional({
>       error = "invalid_client";
>   })

[image]

What is wrong with this code? Am I sending the wrong parameters or headers? Did I forget something?

***Note:*** The `client_id` and `client_secret` are correct

**- If there is anything unclear, please message me -**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After multiple days and 2 questions later, I figured it out myself. It was an extremely simple fix, which is frustrating.

All I did was delete the `headers` parameter in the request.

Another option is that you can set `headers` to `nil`.

```
Alamofire.request("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
    response in
    print(response.result)
    print(response.result.value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know how this is working.
In theory, the correct execution is:
- Make a POST request to url:
https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

- set as headers:

  *"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"*

  *"Authorization": "Basic xxxxx"*

Where xxxxx is the base64 encoded string of client_id:client_secret (so client_id string and client_secret separated by :)

- set as body:
  "grant_type": "client_credentials"

This will give you the correct response

eg.

```
{
    "access_token": "BQCJeyp3ocQZzSksvNn3IXuvY0NsYI26YMF400jp-7Dd8zGz6ecXyywwmSdy4jrPWwLZA_6l4e59lu8dYfg",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": ""
}
```

Comment: I uploaded my own answer yesterday evening, all I did was remove the headers and I get the correct result

Comment: Yeah, I see. But it's not correct anyway. I don't know why is working, but you know, is up to you if you want to understand the correct way that the spotify guide show :)


In the "Authorization Code Flow" they say:


`An alternative way to send the client id and secret is as request parameters (client_id and client_secret) in the POST body, instead of sending them base64-encoded in the header.`


Maybe this is valid even in the Client Credential Flow